# Need list in drop down menu to display results after clicking numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, radio-button

I'm trying to figure out how to add the out to the text box underneath the female drop down box when you select in the Female section "80-140" in the text field it should read "Women use 5 Iron" why isn't that not displaying on the screen? Thanks! It is nearly impossible to find an on line tutorial that explains this. Hopefully I am explaining it right. If you run the code it'll make more sense. Again thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE>

    <meta name="keywords" content="CIS 122" />
    <meta name="description" content="Examples of radio buttons, dropdown and function calls in JavaScript" />
    <style type="text/css">
        body{
            background-color: #93BACB;
            width: 800px;
            border: 1px solid #004343;
            margin: 25px auto;
            padding: 25px 25px 10px 25px;
            font-family: Times New Roman; serif;
        }
        h1{
            font-size: 24px;
            line-height: 26px;
            color: #004343;
            text-align: left;
            margin: 10px 0 0 0;
        }
        h2{
            font-size: 16px;
            line-height: 18px;
            color: black;
            text-align: left;
        }
        h3{
            font-size: 32px;
            line-height: 32px;
            color: black;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0;
        }
        input{
            margin-top: 3px;
        }
        .lessonBlock{
            width: 400px;
            border: 1px solid #004343;
            margin: 25px auto 0;
            padding: 0 10px 10px;
            float: left;
        }
        ul{
            margin: 0;
        }
        li{
            list-style-type: none;
        }
        .clear{
            clear: both;
        }
    </style>


    <script language="javascript">
        function getButtonChoice()
        {
            for(var index = 0; index < document.radioTest.fred.length; index++)
            {
                if(document.radioTest.fred[index].checked == true)
                    var radioChoice = document.radioTest.fred[index].value;
            }
            document.radioTest.displayRadio.value = radioChoice;
        }

        function getDropdownChoice()
        {
            document.radioTest.displayDrop.value = document.radioTest.dropChoices.value;
        }

    </script>


<body>

    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>


        <form name="radioTest">
            <input type="radio" name="fred" value="Clubs"  />Male<br />




 <select name="dropChoices" onchange="getDropdownChoice();">Friend
                <option></option>
                <option value=" Men use 5 Iron">140-170</option>
                <option value=" Men 6 Iron">130-160</option>
                <option value="Men use 7 Iron">120-150</option>
```

// the code for the men drop down box works so just trying to figure out why the female section won't work.

```
            </select><br />
               <form name="radioTest">
<input type="radio" name="fred" value="Clubs"  />Female<br />
<select name"dropChoices" onchange="getDropdownChoice();">Friend  
                                <option></option>
                                <option value="Women use 5 Iron">80 - 140</option>
                                <option value="Women use 6 Iron">70- 130</option>
                                <option value="Women use 7 Iron">65 - 120</option>
```

//how do I display this inside the text box underneath the drop down box? I have the male one working.

```
            <input type="text" name="displayDrop" /> 
            <onclick="getButtonChoice();" 
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please share your correct code. I can see the HTML you shared is not correct. Where the select-box is closing (select box for female)? Where is the closing tag of first form? "getButtonChoice" is not given to any input as per the code shared by you. Please correct these things and share the code. It will help to fix the issue soon if code is shared properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have corrected your HTML and JavaScript Code. Please take a look at the code portions given below. Replace your HTML and Script code with the ones given below. This code works fine as per your requirement.

HTML Code -

```
<body>
    <div class="clear"></div>
        <form name="radioTest">
            <input type="radio" name="fred" id="fred_male" value="Clubs"  />Male<br />

    <select name="dropChoices_male" id="dropChoices_male" onchange="getDropdownChoice();">Friend
                <option></option>
                <option value=" Men use 5 Iron">140-170</option>
                <option value=" Men 6 Iron">130-160</option>
                <option value="Men use 7 Iron">120-150</option>
                  </select><br />

               <form name="radioTest">
<input type="radio" name="fred" id="fred_female" value="Clubs"  />Female<br />
<select name="dropChoices_female" id="dropChoices_female" onchange="getDropdownChoice();">Friend  
                                <option></option>
                                <option value="Women use 5 Iron">80 - 140</option>
                                <option value="Women use 6 Iron">70- 130</option>
                                <option value="Women use 7 Iron">65 - 120</option>
                              </select><br />               
   <input type="text" name="displayDrop" onclick="getButtonChoice();" /> 

        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</body>
```

JavaScript Code -

```
 <script language="javascript">
    var radioChoice;

    function getDropdownChoice()
    {     
            document.radioTest.displayDrop.value = '';
            if(document.getElementById("fred_male").checked)
            { 
                var e = document.getElementById("dropChoices_male");
                radioChoice = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
            }
            else if(document.getElementById("fred_female").checked)
            {
                var e = document.getElementById("dropChoices_female");
                radioChoice= e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
            }
            else
            {
                radioChoice = '';
            }
    }
    function getButtonChoice() {
         document.radioTest.displayDrop.value = radioChoice;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm not really sure what the e.options[e.selectedInsex].value; does.

Comment: How do I get the display to show up in the text field?

Comment: In the code e.options[e.selectedIndex].value; takes the selected value from drop-down. In the next line I am storing this value in variable radioChoice and on click event on input function 'getButtonChoice' gets called which saves value stored in radioChoice as the value of input box. This is how value is displaying in text field.

Comment: Did you try changing your code as per the modifications I provided in my answer? Is it working fine as per your requirement?

Comment: it doesn't seem to work so I'm tweeking with the code a little more but it helps me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: I found it working. Please check - http://jsfiddle.net/Ashish_developer/mg5b4v0w/

Answer (score 0):

Ok never mind I hit the text field with enter and it displays the answer is there a way to show it the answer just as text and not a text field? But this works.